# Location-based features in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, geolocation

Not sure if this is possible, but I wanted to check it out.

I want to access the GPS features in iOS, specifically on iPad through my app. Ultimately the goal is to be able to see who else nearby is currently running the app as well. Is this at all possible or practical to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entirely. Check out the documentation on Core Location. Typically the way an app like yours works is that any devices running the app submit their location to a script on your server, then query that script for any other devices nearby.